# Loading animation is not responsive

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I need help to make this loading animation responsive as it is not scaled on different screens

So, How to make it centered in the screen for any screen size

CSS code:

```
.loader {
    font-family: Consolas, Menlo, Monaco, monospace;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 30px;
    opacity: 0.8;
    position: absolute;
    color: #ffffff;
    position: fixed;
    top: 45%;
    left: 35%;
}
.loader span {
    display: inline-block;
    animation: pulse 0.4s alternate infinite ease-in-out;
}
.loader span:nth-child(odd) {
    animation-delay: 0.4s;
}
@keyframes pulse {
to {
    transform: scale(0.8);
    opacity: 0.5;
}
}
```

CSS for preload-overlay

```
/*Section Loading Style*/
.preload-overlay {
    background-color: @background-color;
    color: #434343;
    background: #72bf69;
    align-items: center;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    z-index = 99999;
    text-align: center;
}
```

HTML code, I putted this just before the end of body:

```
 <!-- Start PreLoading -->
    <div class="preload-overlay">
        <div class="loader">
            <span>{</span>
               Loading, Please wait
            <span>}</span>
            ;
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- End PreLoading -->
```

JS code:

```
/*Loading Page script*/
$(window).on('load', function() {

   $(".preload-overlay").fadeOut(1000, function () {
    $("body").css("overflow","auto");
    $(".preload-overlay").remove();
   });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't include your styles for your preload overlay, but, if it is an option, flexbox is your best friend.

```
.preload-overlay {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.loader {
  font-family: Consolas, Menlo, Monaco, monospace;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 30px;
  opacity: 0.8;
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

edit:
I would still use flex if possible. Is there a reason this isn't an option?

```
.preload-overlay {
  background-color: @background-color;
  color: #434343;
  background: #72bf69;
  align-items: center;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  z-index = 99999;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.loader {
  font-family: Consolas, Menlo, Monaco, monospace;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 30px;
  opacity: 0.8;
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

Comment: I have edited and added the missed code, could u please check it again